# AdonisJs cannot find module when deploy in docker

Tags: javascript, node.js, postman, adonisjs-ace

I use adonisJs make api to connect with database
i have a route and call controller to do operation with database
it's work when i run locally (node ace serve --watch)
but when i try to run this code in container (docker)
all route works but there is a problem with only 1 route (put)
but when i send request to this route (postman) it return error

this code to call controller

```js
import Route from "@ioc:Adonis/Core/Route";

Route.post("/pre-gen/", "PreGenerateCouponsController.store").middleware([
  "auth:svms",
]);

Route.post(
  "/pre-gen/move-old-coupons",
  "PreGenerateCouponsController.moveOldCoupons"
).middleware(["auth:svms"]);

Route.put(
  "/pre-gen/:retentionDate",
  "PregenerateCouponsController.retention"
).middleware(["auth:svms"]);

Route.delete("/pre-gen/reset", "PreGenerateCouponsController.reset").middleware(
  ["auth:svms"]
);
```

```js
{
    "message": "Cannot find module '/home/node/app/app/Controllers/Http/PregenerateCouponsController'\nRequire stack:\n- /home/node/app/node_modules/@adonisjs/fold/build/src/Ioc/ImportAliases.js\n- /home/node/app/node_modules/@adonisjs/fold/build/src/Ioc/index.js\n- /home/node/app/node_modules/@adonisjs/fold/build/index.js\n- /home/node/app/node_modules/@adonisjs/application/build/index.js\n- /home/node/app/node_modules/@adonisjs/assembler/build/src/requireHook/ioc-transformer.js\n- /home/node/app/node_modules/@poppinss/utils/build/src/esmRequire.js\n- /home/node/app/node_modules/@poppinss/utils/build/index.js\n- /home/node/app/node_modules/@adonisjs/require-ts/build/src/Compiler/index.js\n- /home/node/app/node_modules/@adonisjs/require-ts/build/index.js\n- /home/node/app/node_modules/@adonisjs/assembler/build/src/requireHook/index.js\n- /home/node/app/node_modules/@adonisjs/assembler/build/register.js\n- internal/preload",
    "stack": "Error: Cannot find module '/home/node/app/app/Controllers/Http/PregenerateCouponsController'\nRequire stack:\n- /home/node/app/node_modules/@adonisjs/fold/build/src/Ioc/ImportAliases.js\n- /home/node/app/node_modules/@adonisjs/fold/build/src/Ioc/index.js\n- /home/node/app/node_modules/@adonisjs/fold/build/index.js\n- /home/node/app/node_modules/@adonisjs/application/build/index.js\n- /home/node/app/node_modules/@adonisjs/assembler/build/src/requireHook/ioc-transformer.js\n- /home/node/app/node_modules/@poppinss/utils/build/src/esmRequire.js\n- /home/node/app/node_modules/@poppinss/utils/build/index.js\n- /home/node/app/node_modules/@adonisjs/require-ts/build/src/Compiler/index.js\n- /home/node/app/node_modules/@adonisjs/require-ts/build/index.js\n- /home/node/app/node_modules/@adonisjs/assembler/build/src/requireHook/index.js\n- /home/node/app/node_modules/@adonisjs/assembler/build/register.js\n- internal/preload\n    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:956:15)\n    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:804:27)\n    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:19)\n    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)\n    at ImportAliases.resolve (/home/node/app/node_modules/@adonisjs/fold/build/src/Ioc/ImportAliases.js:99:23)\n    at ImportAliases.resolveAsync (/home/node/app/node_modules/@adonisjs/fold/build/src/Ioc/ImportAliases.js:117:25)\n    at Ioc.import (/home/node/app/node_modules/@adonisjs/fold/build/src/Ioc/index.js:280:42)\n    at Ioc.makeAsync (/home/node/app/node_modules/@adonisjs/fold/build/src/Ioc/index.js:391:40)\n    at IocResolver.call (/home/node/app/node_modules/@adonisjs/fold/build/src/Resolver/index.js:90:47)\n    at Object.PreCompiler.runRouteHandler [as fn] (/home/node/app/node_modules/@adonisjs/http-server/build/src/Server/PreCompiler/index.js:47:51)",
    "code": "MODULE_NOT_FOUND"
}
```

i don't know why because other route is in same file but it's work normally
i try to change methods to post but it still the same

sorry in my weak english language
thanks for helps.

Comment: Can You paste your controller code here ?

Comment: Looks like a typo. Should be `PreGenerateCouponsController` (capital _"G"_) if it's supposed to match the others. Docker runs Linux containers with case-sensitive filesystems

Comment: Thanks for @Phil it's really typo , but it can run locally because i ran in windows